# Eclipse send build to our old account after we change it

Tags: codenameone

for technical reasons we need to change our codenameone account and all our proyects, we created the new account correctly, and on eclipse plugin we loging with the new account, (we had to reset our password in the old account).
The problem is when we try to send the build to the new account, all the builds are sending to the old account. whats the problem?
How must we change to send the builds to the new account.
Regards.

Comment: I think there are a problem with the two accounts, https://cloud.codenameone.com/buildapp/index.html and https://cloud.codenameone.com/secure/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open regedit and delete all of the usage of codename1 and codenameone you can find. On the web you need to delete all cookies and storage related to the domain auth.codenameone.com. This should let you relogin properly.